# How to add custom UI elements inside chat window using MS Teams Toolkit?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I previously worked on creating VSTO and Office addins for MS Outlook, Excel and Word using C# VS. Now I have a plan to build one for MS teams. So, I checked online and found the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview).

But I didn't found that how I can add custom UI elements (text, buttons etc.) inside a chat window. For example: [Teams suggested replies shows suggestions inside button above the chat textbox](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/cbca283e-3f58-41e8-a8d0-5507c2f394ed.png).

Do anybody have an idea that how I can achieve this one?

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/design-teams-app-overview

Answer (score 0):

you might want to start with these docs:

build a [command-response bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-commandbot?tabs=vscode) that you can customize the messages in chat window to either text or adaptive cards (on which you can have buttons).

and [notification bot doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-notificationbot?tabs=vscode) which has more information on customizing adaptive card for Teams apps.

there are also docs on message extension on the same doc site, you can take a look to decide which is what you want to build.